# Javascript adjust object coordinates after canvas crop

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to crop my current canvas background using coordinates, and the canvas have some moveable object.

The movable object which allow moved by mousemove.

```
var object = {
         x: 250, 
         y: 200, 
         h: 16,
         w:50
}
```

Let say i want to crop the canvas start from (100, 200) and crop size is 200*150.

So I resize the new canvas to 200*150 and draw the cropped area here.

```
ctx.drawImage(image,
    100, 200,   // Start at 100, 200 pixels from the left and the top of the image (crop),
    200, 150,   // "Get" a `200 * 150` (w * h) area from the source image (crop),
    0, 0,     // Place the result at 0, 0 in the canvas,
    200, 150); // With as width / height: 200 * 150 (actual cropped area)
```

How to adjust my current object coordinates after canvas crop? In this case the object are in the cropped area.

[image]

Comment: x = 250 - 100 = 150  
y = 200 - 120 = 80

Comment: Its work, here the example: https://jsfiddle.net/wbLqzde3/1/